# Tricky trigonometric problem

Tags: trigonometry

I can not seem to solve this type of easy problem, it seems somewhat tricky, can I have a hint or an explanation.

The problem: $sin\left(2x\right)\:=\:\sqrt{3}cos\left(\:\frac{3\pi \:}{2}-x\right)$ on the interval $[ ; \frac{7}{2}
]$

Answer (score 3):

The hint:
$$\cos\left(\frac{3\pi}{2}-x\right)=-\sin{x}$$ and
$$\sin2x=2\sin{x}\cos{x}.$$
Can you end it now?

Comment: can you do a bit of explanation

Comment: @James Try to use, what I wrote. Did you try?

Answer (score 3):

Since $$\sin(2x)=2\sin(x)\cos(x)$$ and $$\cos(3/2\pi-x)=-\sin(x)$$ we get
$$\sin(x)(2\cos(x)+\sqrt{3})=0$$ to solve.

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo, just corrected.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\sqrt{3}\cdot \cos(\frac{3\pi}{2}-x)\\
=\sqrt{3}\cdot \sin(\frac{3\pi}{2}+\frac{\pi}{2}-x)\\
= \sqrt{3}\cdot \sin(2\pi-x)\\
= \sqrt{3}\cdot \sin(-x)\\
= -\sqrt{3}\cdot \sin(x)\\
$$

$$
\sin 2x = 2\sin x\cos x
$$

$$
\therefore,\\\
2\sin x\cos x = -\sqrt{3}\cdot \sin(x)\\
$$
Now don't go cancelling stuff away first, acknowledge $\bf{\sin x=0}$ as a solution first.
$$
2\cos x = -\sqrt{3}\\
\bf{\cos x = -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}}
$$
The two bolded parts give solutions and they are probably easy for you to work with.